# App login screen is from salesforce and I cant click on any element

Tags: salesforce, detox

I testing an app that has salesforce had the login page (iframe with salesforce  login page)
When trying to interact with the login page, I cant get to any element 
Inspector element shows ״android.webkit.WebView״ and I cant inspect on ant of the element

same for appium or mobiledriver

Answer (score 0):

You are in a `WebView`, which unfortunately detox doesn't play nice with.
What I would do is add a `TestID` to the `WebView`, then do something alongside:

`await element(by.id('sales-force-webview-login')).tapAtPoint({ x: 250, y: 250 });`

Where `x` and `y` are the pixel location of the input (for example user-name and password input fields).